# Replacing text after ":"

Tags: java, qr-code

I'm developing an app to read QR code via ZXing. The code run flawlessly but i'm having problem meddling with the scanned result because i wanted to change certain word from it. consider the scanned result is this:

```
ID: 1001 Detail: RM9999
```

what should i do if i wanted to change the "9999" in the string above with another string? lets say it is

```
String a1 = 1500
```

so the expected outcome would be

```
ID: 1001 Detail: RM1500
```

edited:

@Bohemian So the actual problem is my QR code actually display like this:

```
ID: 1001 
Detail: RM9999
```

instead of the linear line that i show earlier. any workaround for this?

Comment: And what is the rule?  Is the number to be replaced always the last 4 digits of the string?

Comment: rule is that
"ID: " <- fixed
"1001 " <- varies from 101,1001,10001,999 etc
"Detail: " <- come after the above, fixed
"RM" <- fixed
"9999" <- varies to any number. in fact, its even better if it can be displayed with 2 decimal minimum. 
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind:

```
String s = stringFromQr.replaceAll("(?<=: RM)9999", "1500");
```

Which means replace all occurrences of "9999" preceded by ": RM" with "1500".

Edit, to answer comments, you can do:

```
String s = stringFromQr.replaceAll("(?<=: RM)" + Pattern.quote(stringToReplace), stringToReplaceWith);
```

Note that I used `Pattern.quote` to escape any regular expression effect from it.

Comment: your code works! but instead of fixed "9999" how do i make it to be variable? and is it possible to make the result show 1500.00 instead of 1500 only?

Comment: Yes for both. You can construct the strings as you want.

Comment: im sorry but what would be the string look like? never learn about this :(

Comment: but i wanted to replace the 9999, and the 9999 can be anything. maybe 8888. if use pattern.quote("9999"), i only able to replace 9999 with new string. what if the string is 8888? it wont work :(

Comment: In this case - use a wildcard: `"(?<=: RM).*"`

Answer (score 0):

This uses a look-behind to match input variable digits in it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String input = "ID: 1001 Detail: RM9999";
    String a1 = "1500";
    String result = input.replaceAll("(?<=ID: \\d{1,4} Detail: [A-Z]{1,2})\\d+", a1);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 1001 Detail: RM1500
```

This code would also work with `ID: 789 Detail: RM123` or `ID: 66 Detail: X55` for example

Comment: for some reason, this line wont work on android. i've edited my main post for the code

Comment: for some reason, this line wont work on android. i've edited my main post for the code..
Im getting the println of "input" BEFORE the input.replaceAll based on ur code

btw, i know where is the problem. in my qr code the line is actually as edited above. please advice